# Application not installed on phone

Tags: android

I have samsung i5503 galaxy. I got a problem in developing app.

First I attach the phone with pc and turn usb debugging on,install the driver than as i run my app ,my phone is not appeared as running android device. So how can i run and test my app on real device?
Secondly i make apk of my app and than mail it than i open this mail n my phone and try to install the app but error was app not installed.
What is the problem?
my phone's is OS is Android 2.1 (eclair) and firmware version is 2.1 update-1.

Comment: You need to sign it with a key to make it work on the phone. (If you are working with Windows 7, adb drivers have a problem and the phone is not recognized)

Comment: Mr. Sameer..thanks  as i sign my app it is running on my phon  but still i m unable to test the app on phone. means as i run cmd adb devices my phon dosent show in that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml file - the application node should have an attribute *android:debuggable="true"*
, so for the line in total some thing like:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i have done this also, but no change. is this the problem of samsung mobile??

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, if you can't see something like this when you run ./adb devices

```
$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554    device
```

Then I don't know what you can do. So if you get the emulator from the command prompt ok, but it simply doesn't work when you shut that down and plug in the device then I reckon there is something up with your phone. As far as I know any Android phone is capable of being a developer phone.

Answer (score 0):

Its all here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Main points are:   *Turn on "USB Debugging" on your device.
On the device, go to the home screen, press MENU, select Applications > Development, then enable USB debugging.*

And:   *You can verify that your device is connected by executing adb devices from your SDK tools/ directory. If connected, you'll see the device name listed as a "device."*

That last verification of device connection involves a bit of command line action...

Comment: i have done all these things that u told already. but yet unable to get the device from command prompt. can u tell me what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Developing on AIDE, I found that simply refreshing the build (Menu button -> More -> Refresh Build) solved the issue.